# Find and Replace *.txt file generator? web based?

Tags: replace

I want to know how or what would be the best way to achieve the following.

I work with a large eCommerce company and we have to constantly replace images with new images and then clear the cache using a pre-made template. I'll show a small example of the template it's a *.txt file template that I use for refreshing content on "Akamai edge control"

There is about 100 different lines in the text file each a little different but they all contain to sets of generic variables.

```
http://www.mysite.com/file/folder/blah/xxxxxx/_something_else here/zzzzzz/image250
http://www.mysite.com/file/folder/blah/xxxxxx/_something_else here/zzzzzz/image500
http://www.mysite.com/file/folder/blah/xxxxxx/_something_else here/zzzzzz/image800
http://www.mysite.com/file/folder/blah/xxxxxx/_something_else here/zzzzzz/image1000
```

That is just an example of what it looks like in the text file. The thing we do is open the file with Notepad and press Ctrl+h and the replace box pops up. I put in a number could be i.e. "123456" to replace the xxxxxx but I then have to go back to the number and manually change it to "123000" mind you we are only making changes to the xxxxxx and the zzzzzz. They are just place holders. So my end result would be like this...

Ps. on the zzzzzz it always ends with "000"

```
http://www.mysite.com/file/folder/blah/123456/_something_else here/123000/image250
http://www.mysite.com/file/folder/blah/123456/_something_else here/123000/image500
http://www.mysite.com/file/folder/blah/123456/_something_else here/123000/image800
http://www.mysite.com/file/folder/blah/123456/_something_else here/123000/image1000
```

My main question is... is there already some sort of program that can run this process a bit more automatically by just selecting my template file and pasting in my only "123456" and getting all the lines the change while adding the zzzzzz with the zero's also.

I'm trying to eliminate a ton of work and make the process more efficient. My example of "123456" could also be up to "1234567". Maybe even pasting in more then one number separated with commas kind of like "123456,123457,123458" then it runs sample process generating a block of text for each number like it was found and replaced manually.

Ideally I would like to just have a web based form like the image to perform the task, unless there is another way without installing software on over 1000 computers. Hope this make sense. Thanks in advance for any input.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kc5B.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Given a file with full list of UNC paths or FTP paths and credentials for each target file location/server, it would be possible to write a program to read your templates, allow you to input your numbers, and to contact each server in turn and write the new versions.

Given the nature of the beast, the lil' program would have to have logging and crash resistance and probably an interface allowing the operation to be repeated on a subset of machines.

You could also probably continue to update your files manually (PSPAD.EXE has find and replace in files), upload them to a central file server and have each of the web servers download the files irrespective of if they've changed or not - a simple batch file executed by each server's scheduler could do that, of course you'd have to configure each server.

Mark ia.uk.com

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from the phrasing of the question that you are not inclined to see a 'server admin' solution, such as the command line tool sed.

A server administrator would perform this task in this way.  From the folder where your template.txt file is, they would run these two commands:
sed -i 's/xxxxxx/123456/' template.txt
sed -i 's/zzzzzz/123000/' template.txt

Explanation:
 sed - stream the file through this tool and work one line at a time
 -i  - make the changes in place, so save them back to the file they came from
 s/.../... - substitute this for that

Assumptions I am making:
'Ctrl+h' means you are using a Windows machine to download the template, make the changes, and upload the new template.

'for refreshing content on' means that this template is already on a web server, and you have access to that web server.

'large eCommerce company' I am assuming this is a linux web server, and therefore the sed tool is already installed as part of any modern linux operating system.

'Ideally I would like to just have a web based form like the image to perform the task, unless there is another way without installing software on over 1000 computers.' I am assuming you do not have permission from your supervisor to hire a freelance developer to make a single web page with the one number field and a launch button, which would then run the above commands dynamically and perform your ideal solution.

Information I dont know:
Is your template file in one central location, or is it on these 1000 computers?
What is making the image changes?